# How to find a quadratic polynomial with the information given?

Tags: polynomials, quartics

> Let $p(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ (where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$) and $p(1)=10,p(2)=20,p(3)=30$. How can I find the quartic $p(x)$ through the info given?

I know how to start that is firstly considering an equation like $y=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)+ax^4$ but after that it gets a bit confusing as we have to add some specific powers of $x$ with coefficient like $ax^3+bx+d$ on RHS. So my question is how to know which powers of $x$ we have to add in the **above equation**, how to know that other wise if we add $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ then there won't be any use of considering y like I did in the starting. Moreover it becomes quite lengthy if we add more and more terms. How to deal with it?

PS~I have not added the whole question, but written everything I have to ask.

Comment: try substituting the values in $p(x)$. You'll get $3$ equations, each with $4$ variables. Then, you can eliminate $d$ by combining the equations pairwise, to get $3$ equations, in $3$ variables. Fairly easy from here

Comment: Yes I know that method, but in the solution of the same ques I saw that they exactly wrote the eqn like y=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-A) +10x     how can I know that we have to add this or that power of x (with a coefficient suppose b) in the last after writing (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-A)

Comment: write $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-A)+g(x)$ and show that $g(1)=10,g(2)=20,g(3)=30$

Comment: $p(x)-10x$ has three roots $x=1,2,3$.

Comment: You mean to say we will have to think it ourselves, like what relation can be made with the info as they might be simple ones, like some identity will satisfy it?

Comment: @Akshat Saxena : Please put @ if you want to comment to somebody. Yes, and of course, it is not always easy to get something like $10x$ from given info.